# Whats wrong with my math?

Tags: c, floating-point, int

I have a function that involves floats and ints. When I run the code, the result comes out wrong. When I enter 4.3 for the input_voltage, I get 3803 for the decimal and EDB for HEX. The correct answer should be 3808 and EE0. Can anyone tell me what might be going on?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int digital_encoding(float voltage);

int main()
{
    float input_voltage;
    int valid, ch;

    do{
        printf("Please enter the input voltage between 0 and 5 volts: \n");
        valid = scanf("%f", &input_voltage);
        if(input_voltage <= 0){
            printf("Enter a number larger than 0! \n");
            valid = 0;
        }
        if(input_voltage >= 5){
            printf("Enter a number less than 5! \n");
            valid = 0;
        }
    }while(valid != 1);

    digital_encoding(input_voltage);
}
int digital_encoding(float voltage)
{
    int dig_encode;
    dig_encode = ((voltage + 5)*(4095/10));
    printf("The digital encoding equals %d in decimal, and %X in HEX.\n", dig_encode, dig_encode);
    return dig_encode;
}
```

Comment: 4095.0/10 = 409.5, but you're using integer semantics on your division, so getting just 409.  Specify the equation like this: `((voltage+5)*(4095.0/10));` or `((voltage+5)*((double)4095/10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here :

```
int digital_encoding(float voltage)
{
    **int** dig_encode;
    dig_encode = ((voltage + 5)*(4095/10));
    printf("The digital encoding equals %d in decimal, and %X in HEX.\n", dig_encode,    dig_encode);
    return dig_encode;
}
```

Use this instead

```
int digital_encoding(float voltage)
{
    float dig_encode;
    dig_encode = ((voltage + 5)*(4095.00/10));
    printf("The digital encoding equals %d in decimal, and %X in HEX.\n", (int)dig_encode, (int)dig_encode);
    return (int)dig_encode;
}
```

Comment: Um, the only problem is `*(4095/10)`. You fixed that, so no downvote, but the pointless change of `dig_encode`'s type and subsequent casting means no upvote either.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks for pointing that out. I just thought I will make it more readable for him.

Answer (score 6):

`4095/10` is 409 and not 409.5, this is integer arithmetics, so it is rounded down.

You are probably looking for  `4095.0 / 10` [or simply `409.5`]

Comment: "Rounded down" can be confusing when you take negative numbers into account. Use rounded towards zero.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to change (4095/10) to (4095.0/10) else you'll get integer arithmetic on that ratio with the remainder discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here :

```
 int dig_encode;
        dig_encode = ((voltage + 5)*(4095/10));
```

Calculate the result in float and then cast it in int before using it.

```
dig_encode = (int)((voltage + 5)*(4095/10.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Result of `4095/10` is **int**, so it's 409, not 409.5. This is because both numbers are **int**. To make result **float** you can write it like this `4095.0/10`